Расшифровка хеша по сиду
Имеется сид, хеш и множество числел 0-1000, как их расшифровать? из плюсов - можно посмотреть расшифровываемые данные (например первое значение, или 1000 первых значений)
Хэш:878a009d3c98ba63376f49d9ae1fd453891cf15bfb392b260fa6026af2751279120e9cbfc8c81bbda904d68dd4daed39747c260cd6ace6abaa25e150594b3c67
Сид:osPN9c
первые 10 значений:
3.51 2.13 2.64 1.08 1.08 1.59 6.04 1.46 1.32 1.20

что именно вы подразумеваете под «расшифровкой хэша»? ведь в здравом уме и твёрдой памяти никто нигде никогда хэш не шифрует: абсолютно бессмысленное действие.

нет, чисто технически, конечено, как и любую другую информацию, полученный хэш можно и позашифровывать ещё сколько угодно раз, и другие хэширующие функции применить к нему же. но зачем?

Александр, вопрос как получить последовательность чисел из него
